# Highcharts symbol covered by another line

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there a way to define a symbol that covers another symbol? Or the same with points? I have a symbol that is overdrawn by another symbol, but I want a particular one to appear on top. It appears "last drawn line wins" is the rule, but I may like one line to appear on top at one point, and another at a different time.

In this example fiddle from their page, the idea would be to display the cloud above the sun, z-index wise, without reordering the series data.

http://jsfiddle.net/5Les1k6j/1/

```
series: [{
            name: 'London',
            marker: {
                symbol: 'diamond'
            },
            data: [{
                y: 3.9,
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/snow.png)'
                }
            }, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, {
                    y: 26.5,
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/snow.png)'
                }
            }, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        },
        {
            name: 'Tokyo',
            marker: {
                symbol: 'square'
            },
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, {
                y: 26.5,
                marker: {
                    symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)'
                }
            }, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]

        }
        ]
```

Comment: I do not think it is possible to accomplish this without altering the source code of the high charts files.

Comment: "but I may like one line to appear on top at one point, and another at a different time" -- but you are only expecting this from the points/symbols, right? not the drawn line itself (fx where they cross)?

Comment: I'm expecting the symbol to be entirely uncovered. There should not be a line OR point over it.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible (and neither simple). In short, current logic expects whole series (line + markers) be in one `<g>` group. That means you have two groups, one per each series. Unfortunately you can not pick one element from a group, and make it above whole another group, not in SVG. I see two solutions: manually change DOM elements (may cause strange issues, hard to guess) or as in the comment above: change logic in the core. Editing source code shouldn't be necessary, see [extending Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts).

Comment: Thanks, I would accept this as the answer to my question, would you copy/paste it into an answer?